# Проблема с MySQL в OS X 10.8: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: macos, mac, mysql

Создаю рабочее окружении на OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, сконфигурировал Apache2, подгрузил PHP, скачал и установил все компоненты MySQL. Делаю все по инструкциям и в какой-то момент появляется проблема, а именно возникает на стадии создания пароля для root.

Ввожу команду в терминале, как и говорят в инструкции (заменяя на свой пароль, в одинарных ковычках).

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'yourpasswordhere'
```

> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin:
> connect to server at 'localhost'
> failed error: 'Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
> NO)'

И что же делать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

P.S. Уверен, что моя проблема уже всплывала, но она не гуглится в силу того, что OS X не так популярна, как Windows. Да и все, что я нагуглил относится уже к более поздним стадиям работы с MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вводите

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p
```

И это все. Пароль спросит позже

Comment: Окей, ввел.
А что же теперь? Что значит это “позже“?

Comment: Более того, установил phpMyAdmin, сконфигурировал как надо, но при входе на главной выдает ошибку.

> #1045 Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL

Comment: Все, решил проблему. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: ну так в чем причина была?